# How to use using statement with Entities in LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

```
 using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
        {


            var coursequery = from course in entities.Course
            select course;
         }
```

After entering this code into LINQPad just as I would with Visual Studio and adding the connection to my custom Entities assembly, I get the following error message:
**The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.**

This code, however, works just fine in Visual Studio.  Therefore, how do I get LINQPad to emulate the behavior I encounter in Visual Studio when typing in this exact same code?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an Entity Framework connection in LINQPad? If so, LINQPad instantiates the data context for you; all you should do is this (with the Query Language set to 'C# Expression'):

```
from course in Course
select course;
```

or better, just:

```
Course
```

Or set the query language to 'C# Statements' and do this:

```
Course.Dump();
```

If it still complains about the connection string, make sure that you've entered the details correctly in LINQPad's connection properties dialog.

If you still want to instantiate `MyEntities` manually, you'll need to provide a valid connection string - either via the constructor or the application configuration file, which should be named **linqpad.config** and put in the same folder as LINQPad.exe.

Comment: What is the format of the connectionString I have to provide to MyEntities in LINQPad?  I tried the full connectionString from my Web.config file, but that was not accepted as valid.